# find closest distance between two numbers (looking for improvement)

Tags: javascript, mathematics

Let's say I have a number set like below

```
// 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Now I want to go from `2` to `5`. To go from `2` to `5` there are two ways: one is forwards and another is backwards

```
forwards: +3
backwards: -5
```

Backwards is basically going to backside from `2` and reaching `5` from end of numbers

ex

`-5` goes like this: `2 -> 1 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5`

so there are some examples how the function should return

```
    from  to    max    result
    2     5     8      3
    1     8     8     -1
    8     1     8      1
    7     1     8      2
    8     5     8     -3
```

I have created one function which is working as expected but I am sure there must be other good ways to achieve the same result. I'm looking for improvement in my function or maybe a full newly created function which is more simple.
Thanks in advance

**Here is my code**

```js
function findClosest(from, to, max) {
    let isReversed = from > to
    if(isReversed) {
        let hold = to
        to = from; from = hold
    }
    let rDiff = max - to,
        forwordDis = to - from,
        backwordDis = from + rDiff,
        result = forwordDis < backwordDis? forwordDis : -backwordDis
    if(isReversed) { result -= result*2 }
    return result
}

console.log(findClosest(2,5,8))
console.log(findClosest(1,8,8))
console.log(findClosest(8,1,8))
console.log(findClosest(7,1,8))
console.log(findClosest(8,5,8))
```

Comment: I have a question, the set you receive as parameter comes always sorted?

Comment: yes .................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your initial approach, but I couldn't understand your execution... There are a few things I might add to it and few thing I might remove. My style of writing code always goes after readability first and optimization second. If I can achieve both then that's a bonus...

### Your approach my way

Actually I had the same idea as soon as I read your problem statement but well you executed it first so its no longer my idea.

Here is how I interpreted your approach...

```
The number scale
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
```

Lets choose two variables, in which one will act as a starting node and one will act as the ending node (In other words from and to). I am going with your pick, `from = 2 => f` and `to = 5 => t`

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
  |     |
  f     t
```

Now to find the distance I need to find the absolute difference between `from` and `to`

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
  |     |
  f~~3~~t
```

Okay, now I have my absolute difference... This means I need to travel three nodes from 2 to reach 5, but I can also travel the other way around. Therefore I will call my absolute difference as `forwards`

To travel the other way around, I need to know two offsets. One is from the start of my number scale to my `from` and other is from the end of my number scale to my `to`

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
  |     |
< 1     3 >
```

Okay... I now have my 2 offsets I will name them `leftOffset => 1` and `rightOffset => 3`

To get the reverse distance,(I shall call it `backwards`) I need to add my two offsets and one for link between end and start. Therefore `backwards = leftOffset + rightOffset + 1 => 5`

Okay now that everything is set, I need to find the minimum distance. In this case it will be the `forwards` variable... But the values of my `from` and `to` can vary. So, what if their values are reversed `from = 5, to = 2`

In this case the variables `forwards` and `backwards` exchange their meaning. Therefore I need to react the same way and check if my calculations are correct. To do this I will just negate the final result, if my `from` is greater than `to`

Here is my version of your code (I also made it so that you can change your number series, using the min value):

```js
function findClosest(from, to, min, max){
    let smaller = (from > to) ? to : from,
        bigger = (from < to) ? to : from;
    
    let leftOffset = smaller - min,
        rightOffset = max - bigger;
    
    let forwards = bigger - smaller,
        backwards = leftOffset + rightOffset + 1;
    
    let result = (backwards > forwards) ? forwards : -backwards;
    result = (from > to) ? -result: result;
    
    return result
}
console.log("Input: (from, to, min, max), Output: (minimum distance)");
// ---- Your Test Cases ---- //
console.log("Input: (2, 5, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosest(2, 5, 1, 8)); // 3
console.log("Input: (1, 8, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosest(1, 8, 1, 8)); // -1
console.log("Input: (8, 1, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosest(8, 1, 1, 8)); // 1
console.log("Input: (7, 1, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosest(7, 1, 1, 8)); // 2
console.log("Input: (8, 5, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosest(8, 5, 1, 8)); // -3

// -- My custom test case -- //
console.log("Input: (2, 5, 2, 5), Output: " + findClosest(2, 5, 2, 5)); // -1
```

### Now for my next approach

Everything you have seen above remains the same, but now I don't calculate the offsets. Instead I calculate the total number of elements.

Since I have my `forwards` variable set to my absolute difference... It is actually the length of my line segment from 2 to 5 on my number scale.

Then I can just subtract this segment from number scale to get the reverse distance

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
  |     |
  |~~3~~|
  |~seg~|

1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
|~~~~~~8~~~~~~|
|~ num-scale ~|

seg - num-scale
|~|~ 5 ~|~~~~~|
```

Everything else remains the same...

Hence here is the code (Yes, I also made this code to be series extensible):

```js
function findClosestTwo(from, to, min, max){
    let smaller = (from > to) ? to : from,
        bigger = (from < to) ? to : from;
    
    let totalNumberOfElements = max - min + 1;
    
    let forwards = bigger - smaller,
        backwards =  totalNumberOfElements - forwards;

    let result = (forwards < backwards) ? forwards : -backwards;
    
    result = (from > to) ? -result : result;

    return result;
}
console.log("Input: (from, to, min, max), Output: (minimum distance)");
// ---- Your Test Cases ---- //
console.log("Input: (2, 5, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosestTwo(2, 5, 1, 8)); // 3
console.log("Input: (1, 8, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosestTwo(1, 8, 1, 8)); // -1
console.log("Input: (8, 1, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosestTwo(8, 1, 1, 8)); // 1
console.log("Input: (7, 1, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosestTwo(7, 1, 1, 8)); // 2
console.log("Input: (8, 5, 1, 8), Output: " + findClosestTwo(8, 5, 1, 8)); // -3

// -- My custom test case -- //
console.log("Input: (2, 5, 2, 5), Output: " + findClosestTwo(2, 5, 2, 5)); // -1
```

If you are crazy about the optimizations, you can technically compress both the functions in a single line.

Note: I have not used any in-built math functions in JavaScript for performance of course.

Note: These functions should in theory be very convenient for you to use as you never have to deviate and change the min and max values.

Note: You can also increase your number scale to include negative values.

Edit: I just now got the previous answer to your question... His approach is kind of like my second function but different in theory. I did not even read his answer because the names and comments made me dizzy. Its a cool approach though, nice one fam.

Comment: i must say you have a really clean code i just understand everything in one read also it is solving the problem flawlessly , previous answer was solving the problem with proper technique to work with negetives also but i liked your code obviously for readability and technique both

Comment: Glad I could help you... I prefer a readable code instead of writing comments. I have a bad habit of not commenting stuff so I try my hardest to make everything readable. The habit of not writing comments has bitten me back a few times now, made me a whole new person.

Comment: i think i should follow your practice

Answer (score 1):

### Optimization / Simplification

Your code can be converted into the following

```js
// Let X be a subset of Z (the integers) from a to b.
// Calculate the shortest distance between x_a and x_b
// using the forward and backward metrics

// THIS ALGORITHM ASSUMES THAT a < b
function findClosest(a, b, x_a, x_b) {
    // common distance between a and b in the number line
    let l1Norm = Math.abs(x_a - x_b);
    let numberOfElements = b - a + 1;
    let backwardsDistance = numberOfElements - l1Norm;

    let minDist = (l1Norm < backwardsDistance)? l1Norm : -backwardsDistance;

    return x_a < x_b? minDist : -minDist;
}

console.log(findClosest(1, 8, 2, 5))
console.log(findClosest(1, 8, 1, 8))
console.log(findClosest(1, 8, 8, 1))
console.log(findClosest(1, 8, 7, 1))
console.log(findClosest(1, 8, 8, 5))

console.log(findClosest(-7, 8, 4, 5))
console.log(findClosest(-7, 8, 5, 4))
```

**Please note that this solution applies for any integer number set instead of `1 to n` sets**

### The why of this code is more of a resolution using a diagram:

[image: explanation img]

It turns out that as the set is an integer one, it's countable.

We are asked to compute the distances forward and backwards, so, our set which usually is represented with a line of numbers, can be converted into a circle. Where we will find that there's a relation between the forward and backward distances through the number of elements in the set.

*Sometimes (specially in data structures class) we should draw something to give us an "outside" view about a problem.*

Well, I hope this helps you!

Comment: well you have described things quite well i will be accepintg your result after some days to get more answer that graph helped understand well about your version of code thanks for your time and knowledge